# How to find the difference between 2 dataframes?

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes which are "exactly" the same. The difference between them is that one has 676 observations (rows) and the second has 666 observations. I don't know which of those rows are missed in a second dataframe.

Would be the easiest to me if someone can show me the code how to make a third dataframe with those 10 rows which are missed.

The name of dataframes:
- dataset1 (676)
- dataset2 (666)

Thx.

Comment: do you have unique row identifiers in both the tables?

Comment: Nope, that would be easy if I have any specific numbers of each row or something. The problem is that one dataframe is transformed from the other one and I don't know why while this transformation I lose those 10 rows...

Comment: In that case you may want to post the piece of code that creates dataset2 too.

Comment: If the transformation isn't that hard to recreate you could add the row identifiers to data set 1 before the transformation. `datset1$ID <- 1:nrow(dataset1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dataset1[tail(!duplicated(rbind(dataset2, dataset1)), nrow(dataset1)), ]
```

Comment: I +1'ed (its a clever solution) then held back: I think you should explain it a bit. As per usual though, cool beans!

Comment: Doesn't this assume that all the rows in the first dataset are all unique?

Comment: @TylerRinker yeah- I was going to suggest to stick in a `unique(dataset)` in there, but that's not correct. The OP needs to define whether "missing" a duplicated row matters or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach:

```
library(qdap)

## generate random problem
prob <- sample(1:nrow(mtcars), 1)    
## remove the random problem row
mtcars2 <- mtcars[-prob, ]   
## Throw it into a list of 2 dataframes so they're easier to work with
dat <- list(mtcars, mtcars2)   
## Use qdap's `paste2` function to paste all columns together
dat2 <- lapply(dat, paste2)   
## Find the shorter data set
wmn <- which.min(sapply(dat2, length))
## Add additional element to shorter one
dat2[[wmn]] <- c(dat2[[wmn]], NA)
## check each element of the 2 pasted data sets for equality
out <- mapply(identical, dat2[[1]], dat2[[2]])

## Which row's the problem
which(!out)[1]
which(!out)[1] == prob
```

If `which(!out)[1]` equals `NA` problem is in the last row.

When you start seeing `FALSE` that's where the problem is located.

**EDIT**: removed the `for` loop

Comment: I did Thomas for others.  I am usually hesitant to add additional comments when a poster has put so little work into making a question.  I typically would not have answered such a poorly formatted (lazy) question but the problem itself was fun and interesting.  It's hard to compare answers now b/c we each had generate our own data set rather than the poster making a MWE.

Answer (score 0):

I would say try to use `merge` and then look for where the merge result has `NA` values.

Here's an example using dummy data:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100))
df2 <- df1[-sample(1:100,10),]
dim(df1)
# [1] 100   2
dim(df2)
# [1] 90  2
out <- merge(df1,df2,by='x',all.x=TRUE)
in1not2 <- which(is.na(out$y.y))
in1not2
# [1]  6 25 33 51 52 53 57 73 77 82
```

Then you can extract:

```
> df1[in1not2,]
           x           y
6  -0.8204684  1.76728727
25  0.6198257 -0.10019074
33  0.3876716  0.53149619
51  0.3981059  0.45018710
52 -0.6120264 -0.01855983
53  0.3411197 -0.31806837
57 -0.3672215  1.00002880
73  0.6107264  0.45699881
77 -0.4432919  0.78763961
82 -0.1351786  0.98389557
```